# Scope chaining with optionally parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

currently I have the following type of code

```
scope :scope1, lambda{|param| where(param1: params)}
scope :scope2, lambda{|param| where(param2: params)}
```

and in the controller I would do

```
results = Model.some_other_scope

if !params[:param1].blank?
 results = results.scope1(params[:param1])
end

if !params[:param2].blank?
 results = results.scope2(params[:param2])
end
```

this is not very efficient since it does several calls to DB instead of one.

Is there a way to chain these scopes so it will be disabled if the params don't exist?

```
results = Model.scope1(params[:param1]).scope2(params[:param2])
```

currently, chaining doesn't work because of the where clause doesn't return anything then the whole chain breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `ActiveRecord` queries are evaluated lazily, so, simplyfying, this code produces only one DB call. So your problem doesn't really exist.